# Commerce module can't be enabled

Tags: commerce

I have installed the Commerce module but when I want to enable it, it does not give me the opportunity to check the checkbox, do you know how I can solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Did you install the module via composer? If not, maybe a dependency is missing? But that should be mentioned in the "Extend" page or if you use drush it should be reported in the terminal.

Comment: As the project page states, `Commerce 2.x should only be installed via Composer. The zip files on this page are provided for informative purposes only.`

Comment: thank you very much, I'm not very expert, where can I find the composer?

Comment: Get composer: https://getcomposer.org/, how it integrates with Drupal: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/manage-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

**Manually**

If you install the module manually then module dependencies are not getting installed automatically. Some required dependent modules might be missing. If you add these dependent missing modules manually then it works.

**Using composer**

If you install the module using composer then that module is installed with their dependencies,  and there is no need to manually install the dependency modules.

For best practices use composer for module installation.

Refer to this documentation for the installation of the commerce module :
https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/install-update/installation

Also refer to this document for installing modules using composer:
https://modulesunraveled.com/drupal-8-composer-and-configuration-management/installing-and-uninstalling-modules-composer